# Javascript for each loop only showing last object

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Could someone explain why my loop is only showing the last object of my array?
Because I would like to output all the responses for my quiz
Thank you!**

```
var allQuestions = [
    {
      question: "Welk kerstnummer draai jij grijs tijdens de feestdagen?",
      responses: [{
        text: 'Feliz Navidad',
        value: 10
      },
      {
        text: 'Baby, Its Cold Outside',
        value: 6
      },

    var currentQuestion = 0;
    var question;
    var responses;

    var questions = document.getElementById("question");
    var quizForm = document.getElementById("choiceList");

    function showQuestion() {
      question = allQuestions[currentQuestion].question;
      // choice = allQuestions[answers].responses.length;

      questions.innerHTML = "<p>" + question + "</p>";

      for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[currentQuestion].responses.length; i++) {
        responses = allQuestions[currentQuestion].responses[i].text;
        quizForm.innerHTML = "<li>" + responses + "</li>";
      }
    }

    showQuestion();
```

Comment: change to `quizForm.innerHTML += "<li>" + responses + "</li>";`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `quizForm.innerHTML += "<li>" + responses + "</li>";` but it's not efficient.

I woul prefer do this:

```
var liEl = document.createElement("li");
liEl.innerText = "someContent";
quizForm.appendChild(liEl);
```

```js
let containerElement = document.getElementById("container");
let array = ['a','b','c']


for(let i = 0; i<array.length ; i++){
  containerElement.innerHTML += '<li>'+array[i]+'</li>';
}

array = ['x','y','z']

for(let i = 0; i<array.length ; i++){
  var liEl = document.createElement("li");
  liEl.innerText = array[i];
  containerElement.appendChild(liEl);
}
```

```html
<ul id="container"></ul>
```